# Wigner function in quantum teleportation

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-teleportation, wigner-transform

I'm starting to manipulate Wigner function and I'm studying the Wigner function approach in Quantum Teleportation.
My reference for this is page 29-30 of Braunstein and Van Loock "Quantum teleportation with continuous variables": https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0410100

I have a small issue with a factor and I think I'm neglecting something, because I'm quite sure Brainstein calculations are exact.

At page 30 he gets to the Wigner function
\begin{equation}
W_{out}(x_u, p_v, x'_2, p'_2)=\int dx_{in}dp_{in}W_{in}(x_{in}, p_{in})W_{EPR}(x_{in}-\sqrt{2}x_u,x'_2-\sqrt{2}x_u, \sqrt{2}p_v-p_{in}, p'_2-\sqrt{2}p_v)
\end{equation}
where $ W_{EPR}$ is the Wigner function of an EPR state with finite squeezing, namely
\begin{equation}
W_{EPR}(x_1, x_2, p_1, p_2)=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\exp(-e^{-2r}[(x_1+x_2)^2+(p_1-p_2)^2]-e^{2r}[(x_1-x_2)^2+(p_1+p_2)^2])
\end{equation}
What I want to obtain is the Wigner function of the teleported state $W_{out}(x'_2, p'_2)$ so Braunstein integrates over $x_u$ and $p_v$ and he gets
\begin{equation}
W_{out}(\alpha'_2)=\frac{1}{\pi e^{-2r}}\int d^2\alpha_{in}W_{in}(\alpha)\exp\left(-\frac{|\alpha'_2-\alpha_{in}|^2}{e^{-2r}} \right)
\end{equation}
where $\alpha_{in}=x_{in}+ip_{in}$, which is more or less what I get except for a factor of $1/2$. Since the Wigner function by its definition should be automatically normalized I don't get where this factor comes from, even because the calculation seem pretty straightforward to me.

My calculation:
\begin{equation}
W_{EPR}(x_{in}-\sqrt{2}x_u,x'_2-\sqrt{2}x_u, \sqrt{2}p_v-p_{in}, p'_2-\sqrt{2}p_v)=\\\frac{4}{\pi^2}\exp(-e^{-2r}[(x_{in}+x'_2-2\sqrt{2}x_u)^2+(2\sqrt{2}p_v-p_{in}-p'_2)^2]-e^{2r}[(x_{in}-x'_2)^2+(p'_2-p_{in})^2])
\end{equation}
and, for example, integrating out the $x_u$ part gives me a factor of $\sqrt{\pi/8e^{-2r}}$ and the same goes for the $p_v$ part so that in the end I'm left with
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2\pi e^{-2r}}\exp(-e^{2r}(x_{in}-x'_2)^2+(p'_2-p_{in})^2])
\end{equation}
so you see that I have an extra $1/2$ factor. Any idea of where it may come from? I thought that maybe I had to substitute $x_{in}$ with the corresponding function $x_{in}=(x_u+x_v/\sqrt{2})$ but theoretically the dependence of $x_{in}$ on $x_u$ should be directly in the $x_{in}$ integral.

Comment: This is good place for this type of questions: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/